# How to resolve scoped service inside singleton object

Tags: c#, .net-core, memorycache

I have `MemoryCache` objects (Application,Configuration etc) which I registered them as `Singleton`. Also there are scoped repositories which selects data from db to fill cache.

For example here is the Singleton registered class,

```
public class ApplicationCache : MultipleLoadCache<Application>
{
    public ApplicationCache() 
    {
            
    }
}
```

`MultipleLoadCache` overrides the `CacheItemPolicy`, (there is also `SingleLoadCache`),

```
public class MultipleLoadCache<TEntity> : SmartCache<TEntity> where TEntity : class
{
    public MultipleLoadCache()
    {
    }

    protected override CacheItemPolicy SetPolicy()
    {
        return new CacheItemPolicy()
        {
           AbsoluteExpiration = DateTimeOffset.Now.AddSeconds(15)
        };
    }
 }
```

And base class is,

```
public class SmartCache<TEntity> : IDisposable where TEntity : class
{
      public bool TryGetList(IRepository<TEntity> repository, out List<TEntity> valueList)
      {
          valueList = null;
          lock (cacheLock)
          {
              GenerateCacheIfNotExists(repository, out valueList);
              if (valueList == null || valueList.Count == 0)
              {
                valueList = (List<TEntity>)_memoryCache.Get(key);
              }
          }

          return valueList != null;
      }
```

I know that scoped services can't be injected to singleton class. So I prefer to use method injection.

```
private void GenerateCacheIfNotExists(IRepository<TEntity> repository, out List<TEntity> list)
{
          list = null;
          if (!_memoryCache.Any(x => x.Key == key)) // if key not exists, get db records from repo.
          {
              IEnumerable<TEntity> tempList = repository.GetList();
              list = tempList.ToList();
              _cacheItemPolicy = SetPolicy();
              SetCacheList(list);
          }
      }
}
```

And at controller I try to get cache values, but this part seems wrong to me. If I try to get cache values, I shouldn't pass repository as parameter.

```
private readonly ApplicationCache _appCache;
public LogController(ApplicationCache appCache)
{
   _appCache = appCache;
}

[HttpPost]
[Route("Register")]
public List<Application> Register([FromServices] IApplicationRepository repository)
{
   List<Application> cf;
   _appCache.TryGetList(repository, out cf);

   return cf;
}
```

Also, by doing Method Injection. I am also unable to use `RemovedCallBack` event of `CacheItemPolicy`. Because, when callback triggers (reload cache), I need repository to get records from db again.

Is this design seems nice, what is the best design to do this by using callback events of `MemoryCache`?

**Update 1-**

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
     services.AddControllers();
     services.AddMemoryCache();
     services.AddSingleton(x => new ApplicationCache());
     services.AddScoped<IApplicationRepository, ApplicationRepository>();
}
```

Thanks,

Comment: You should have a class DataRepository class with two dependencies 1 - Caching layer and 2- DataAccess Layer.. So that you can inject these two dependencies the way you want...

Comment: Can you show your `Startup` `ConfigureServices` routine where you inject everything?

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya this question has nothing to do with the "Repository" *anti*pattern. It's specifically about using a scoped service, something already documented in the .NET Core docs

Comment: Using a scoped service inside a singleton is a common problem with hosted services, so it's documented in the Background Services article in [Consuming a scoped service in a Background task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/hosted-services?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio#consuming-a-scoped-service-in-a-background-task). You pass `IServiceProvider` to your singleton and use `CreateScope` explicitly to create a scope, then use that scope objects to create eg DbContext instances

Comment: Check update please @Andy

Comment: Thanks for answer but, Isn't it the same thing, passing ServiceProvider or Repository to method? Or you ment to pass IServiceProvider to constructor? @PanagiotisKanavos

Comment: BTW using low-level repositories (or actually data access objects) on top of higher level ORMs is a *very* bad idea. A DbContext is already a Unit-of-Work (that's why it needs to be scoped), a DbSet is already a repository. Gunnar Peipman's [No need for repository or Unit of Work with EF Core](https://gunnarpeipman.com/ef-core-repository-unit-of-work/) shows how *dangerous such a repository can be. That's not a new idea either, ORM authoers  always warned about[Repository is the new Singleton](https://ayende.com/blog/3955/repository-is-the-new-singleton)

Comment: @Berkay did you check the article? It shows a detailed example of what you want to do, with the context operation marked in orange. Yes, you need to inject `IServiceProvider`. Then explicitly create the scope, and create your DbContext instances from that scope. When the scope gets disposed, so would the scooped service

Comment: I have used IServiceProvider injection before this approach, but I realized that I know the type of repository should be resolved and it seemed wrong way to use the DI container directly. And please correct me if i am wrong, doesn't scoped repository creates its own scope per request? (Btw i am not using EF, executing sp inside repositories) @PanagiotisKanavos

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. Since static classes is compiled at the beginning it cannot inject the required services later. I figured it out by using IServiceScopeFactory.

You basically inject IServiceScopeFactory serviceScopeFactory in the constructer .

```
static SampleClass(IServiceScopeFactory serviceScopeFactory){  
   //serviceScopedFactory will act as Singleton, since it is a static class
   _serviceScopeFactory = serviceScopeFactory;
}
```

And use it like this in the method :

```
using (var scope = _serviceScopeFactory.CreateScope())
{
  var service = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<IService>();
  //Here you can use the service. This will be used as Scoped since it will be 
  //recreated everytime it is called
   
}
```

Comment: So, injecting IServiceScopeFactory inside singleton class won't make factory singleton also? Or is it already singleton registered?

Comment: serviceScopedFactory will be singleton since the class is static

Comment: But the services created using GetRequiredService will be created everytime the method is called. So it is same as scoped.

Comment: You might be missing a spot that static class can't have constructor with parameter.

Comment: Yes i totally missed that since i was using it in a hostedservice. There is this link [Resolving Instances With .Net Core DI in Static Classes](https://www.davidezoccarato.cloud/resolving-instances-with-asp-net-core-di-in-static-classes/) you should check this out

Comment: I have implemented another way thanks for your effort.

Comment: How did you solve it? What is another way you mention? I have the same issue right now. Would you please share your solution as an answer?